# D3.js: How to keep marker and text on same position when zooming in and out

Tags: d3.js, marker

I have a D3.js map based on this: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2374239.

I have added a custom marker and a text on the feature that a user zooms in to a county. However, the marker and text do not stay on the same position as the county when I zoom in or out.  My zoom function is as follows:

```
function zoomToCounty(stname, cntyname) {
    d3.json("/topo/us-wgs84.json", function (us) {
        var t = projection.translate(); // the projection's default translation
        var s = projection.scale() // the projection's default scale

        //initialize marker
        d3.selectAll(".mark").remove();
        d3.selectAll("text").remove();

        //reset active to inactive size and color            
        d3.select("#svgMap2").select("g").select(".active")
            .style("stroke-width", "0.5px")
            .style("stroke", "#808080");

        d3.selectAll(".county")
            .classed("active", function (d) {
                if (d.properties.StateName === stname && d.properties.County === cntyname) {
                    var zoom = d3.zoom()
                    .scaleExtent([1, 6])
                    .on("zoom", zoomed3);

                    svg.select("rect")
                    .call(zoom);

                    var bounds = path.bounds(d),
                    dx = bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0],
                    dy = bounds[1][1] - bounds[0][1],
                    x = (bounds[0][0] + bounds[1][0]) / 2,
                    y = (bounds[0][1] + bounds[1][1]) / 2,

                    scale = 0.9 / Math.max(dx / width, dy / height),
                    translate = [width / 2 - scale * x, height / 2 - scale * y];

                    //get centroid
                    var center = path.centroid(d);

                    //create marker
                    d3.select("#svgMap2").select("g")
                        .append("image")
                        .attr("xlink:href", "/images/marker2.png")
                        .attr("width", 14)
                        .attr("height", 20)
                        .attr("class", "mark")
                        .attr("transform", function (d) {
                            return "translate(" + center + ")";
                        });

                    //add text
                    d3.select("#svgMap2").select("g")
                        .append("text")
                        .style("fill", "#000")
                        .attr("x", x)
                        .attr("y", y)
                        .attr("dy", ".05em")    //set offset y position
                        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  //set anchor y justification
                        .text(cntyname);

            svg.transition()
                .duration(750)
                .call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.translate(translate[0], translate[1]).scale(scale));

            return true;
        }
    })
}); //end d3.json
```

Working website can be found at:  http://realtimeceap.brc.tamus.edu/

Thanks in advance.

01-28-2018 Status:  I'm still unable to fix this one. I just need help on how to keep my image marker and text on the same coordinates as the selected feature when I zoom in/out using the mouse wheel. Initial zoom is at the middle of the svg with scale = 8. How do I make the marker "STICK" to specified coordinates once a user moves the wheel? HELP!

Answer (score 1):

Solved this problem by:
 1.  I called the zoom function on the "g" element then
 2.  I created a function for when user moves the wheel; called this function from the "rect" element.

View the working codes at: http://realtimeceap.brc.tamus.edu